# cant write data from list in csv file

Tags: python

I got this Code:

```
data = [
    {'date':date,
        'field1':beschleunigung_xout_skaliert,
        'field2': beschleunigung_yout_skaliert,
        'field3': beschleunigung_zout_skaliert,
    }

]

with open(r'csv_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['date','field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

If i starting to excecute this, i got the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys' error.

How i am able to fix this ?

Greetings!

Comment: `writer.writerow(data[0])` as you are writing only the first row. or alternatively `writer.writerows(data)` to write "a list of rows"

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy !